# My Contact Became null and not able to insert values

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have an issue that I want to create an attendance for student management visualforce page in that while I am referring a contact and inserting it into a custom object my contact value becomes null

```
public class AttendanceCls{

    //public List<Session__c> UserTemp{get;set;}
    public List<ContactWrapper> listContactWrapper {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> selectedContacts{get;set;}
    List<Attendance__c> Atten = new List<Attendance__c>();
    public List<Session__c> UserTemp = new List<Session__c>();
    Public List<session__c> FetchID = new List <session__c>();
    Public static String Loc;
    Public Static String Cou;
    Public Id selectedSesId{get;set;}

    public AttendanceCls ()
    {
        listContactWrapper = new List<ContactWrapper>();
        searchRecord();
        selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

        for(ContactWrapper wrapContactObj : listContactWrapper) 
        {
            if(wrapContactObj.selected == true) 
            {
                selectedContacts.add(wrapContactObj.acc);

            }
        }         
    }    
    public List<SelectOption> UserList
    {
        get
        {  

            UserTemp = [Select Name, Id, Date__c,Location__c,Course__c From Session__c ];

            UserList = new List<SelectOption>();

            //  system.debug('id testing            '+selectedSesId);

            for(Session__c temp : UserTemp)
            {
                UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Name));
                //      system.debug('Tempid        '+temp.id);

            }

            return UserList;
        }
        set;
    }
    public void searchRecord()
    {

        FetchID = [Select Name, Id, Date__c,Location__c,Course__c From Session__c where id = :selectedSesId ];
        for(Session__c ses : FetchID){
            Loc = ses.Location__c;
            Cou = ses.Course__c;
        }

        listContactWrapper.clear();
        for(Contact a:[select Id, Name,Location__c,Course__c from Contact where RecordTypeId in (SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Student') And Status__c = 'Pursuing' And Location__c =: Loc And Course__c =:Cou limit 1000]) 
        {
            listContactWrapper.add(new ContactWrapper(a));
        }


    }

    public void processSelected() 
    {
        system.debug('contact test');

        for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
              system.debug('Contact c           '+c);
            system.debug('selectedContacts Present      '+selectedContacts);
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Present';
            system.debug('Name      '+c.Name);
            Atten.add(att);
        }
        insert Atten;
        searchRecord();
    }     
    public void DeActivateData() 
    {     
        for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
            system.debug('selectedContacts Absent       '+selectedContacts);
            Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
            att.Name__c = c.Name ;
            att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
            att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
            att.Attedance__c ='Absent';

            Atten.add(att);

        } insert Atten;
        searchRecord();
    }




    // This is our wrapper/container class. 
    public class ContactWrapper 
    {
        public Contact acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}
        public ContactWrapper(Contact a) 
        {
            acc = a; 
            selected = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my code the button reaches correctly to the function

Comment: Can you mention the exact area where you are facing issue ? Also the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking `selectedContacts` list whether it has Contacts in it.

Comment: Hi Junaid thanks for your replay Yes the selectedContacts list contains the contact values init and it is working fine

Comment: I am facing an issue in the processSelected area whenever I click the button it goes to this function but the contact value in the for loop becomes null so the value is not inserting in the Attendance__c custom object

Comment: Inside processSelected method, check whether selectedContacts list has values

Comment: Thank you so much Junaid I have created the selectedContacts in constructor now while transferring it to the function it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the problem isn't very clear, but I think what you have is an issue here, in `processSelected()`:

```
    for(Contact c:selectedContacts){
        Attendance__c att = New Attendance__c();
        att.Name__c = c.Name ;
        att.Course__c = c.Course__c;
        att.Location__c = c.Location__c;
        att.Attedance__c ='Present';
        Atten.add(att);
    }
    insert Atten;
```

If the `Attendance__c` object has a lookup to `Contact`, which it looks like it probably does, you're not populating that lookup with `c.Id`. Copying the `Name` field does not establish a relationship between records.